# Graph skeleton for thorus $S_1$

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose the $g=1$ platonic graph with degree $d=3$ and the number of edges bounding each face is $n=6$ ($v=14$). Is this the skeleton of $S_1$ (the thorus with one hole)?

We know that $K_7$ and the graph with $v=16\;d=n=4$ are the skeletons of $S_1$.
I noticed that both have $d=n$, so my bet is that the answer of the question is negative.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done. You know that [$K_7$ can be embedded on $S_1$](http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~goddard/handouts/cpsc940/surface1.pdf) and in fact can be a triangulation of $S_1$. It will be regular of degree 6 and will have 7 vertices, 21 edges, and 14 triangular faces. Now consider its [dual graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph); it will be regular of degree 3, and will have 14 vertices, 21 edges, and 7 hexagonal faces and by construction will be a skeleton of $S_1$.

Comment: But the graph that I am asking for is degree 3, 14 vertices and 21 edges.

Comment: @user2820579. Thanks. I transposed the 3 and 6 in my original. Fixed now.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Now it comes my question, why this dual graph would be an skeleton of $S_1$? I mean, I could construct, if possible, $S_1$ with my graph without considering that it's the dual of $K_7$. From your answer, it seems to me that duality implies that the graph generates $S_1$.

Comment: In fact, it would appear to me that every graph with genus 1 is a skeleton for $S_1$, is this right?